# asp.net mvc 4 paypal integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal-sandbox

I am new in MVC.I want to integrate PayPal to my website. I try this link http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/asp-net-mvc-paypal-integration/
and everything is ok.And now how to get some information in Redirect action method.My Action metho

```
  public ActionResult RedirectFromPaypal()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In php to do it as follow:

```
$item_number = $_POST["item_number"];
  $item_name = $_POST["item_name"];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal) which goes through setting up checkout and payment with PayPal.  It is very good.  It uses web forms so if you need what something geared towards MVC then have a read of this [tutorial](http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/asp-net-mvc-paypal-integration/).

Both of these combined should have everything you need to get going.

**Update**

For a tutorial on IPN with MVC try [how to use paypal with aspnet mvc](http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2012/06/how-to-use-paypal-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I try this link. First link is in Web Form . But unfortunately
I am new to MVC and I could not translate to MVC. And second link , but here author didn't write about IPN. (Sorry my english :( )

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 links
http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2012/06/how-to-use-paypal-with-asp-net-mvc/
http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.com/2012/01/single-item-paypal-buttons-and.html

Once you get notification on your RedirectFromPaypal() you will call PayPal to get transaction details and the details would be as Key/Value pairs and you can access them as
 string transactionID = Request["txn_id"];
  string sAmountPaid = Request["mc_gross"];